# Como salvar um arquivo no JavaFX ou Java?

Tags: java, javafx

Código que tentei fazer, mas não funciona:

Aplicação FXML do JavaFX:

```
salvar.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
    Stage window = (Stage) cont.getScene().getWindow();
    try {
        String corpo = cont.getText();
        FileWriter gravarFile = new FileWriter(corpo, false);
        PrintWriter gravar = new PrintWriter(gravarFile + ".txt");
        gravar.write(corpo);
        gravar.close();
    }catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Conteudo não poderá ser gravado!");
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
});
```

O que tem de errado neste código acima?

Comment: Olá, defina melhor o erro que está acontecendo, se puder coloque o erro/exception que está sendo lançado.

Answer (score 1):

Não é necessário todo esse esforço no Java 8, pode utilizar o método [`Files#write()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-):

```java
salvar.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
    Stage window = (Stage) cont.getScene().getWindow();
    try {
        String corpo = cont.getText();

        // path do arquivo (incluindo o nome).
        Path path = Paths.get("C:", "teste", "arquivo.txt"); 
        Files.write(path, corpo.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

    }catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Conteudo não poderá ser gravado!");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Os *imports* são todos do pacote [`java.nio.file.*`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

O JavaFX disponibiliza uma janela para abrir/salvar arquivos através da classe [FileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html), que pode ajudar a solucionar seu problema e melhora também a usabilidade do seu software. Eis o código necessário para salvar um arquivo texto:

```
seuBotao.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
        chooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text file (*.txt)", "*.txt"));
        File file = chooser.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);

        if(file != null){
            try {
            // Use o mecanismo de escrita que preferir
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
            writer.write("Escrevendo um arquivo");

            // Não esqueça de fechar o writer
            writer.close();
            } catch (IOException ex){
                // Coloque aqui sua mensagem de exceção
            }       
        }
    }
});
```

Modifique de acordo com suas necessidades. Espero que ajude.