# Como criar um "novo arquivo" .txt no java?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, fxml

Minhas dúvidas são: esse código está correto?
como faço para limpe a tela e abre o novo arquivo criado?

```
menuNovo.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            Stage janela = (Stage) areaTexto.getScene().getWindow();
            String nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nome do arquivo");
            File arquivo = new File(nome + ".txt");
        });
```

[image: como faço para limpe a tela e abre o novo arquivo criado?]

Answer (score 1):

Essa linha é desnecessária:

```
Stage janela = (Stage) areaTexto.getScene().getWindow();
```

`janela` não está sendo utilizado em nenhum lugar dentro do *listener* do evento. Lembrando que eventos podem ser mapeados dentro do próprio arquivo .fxml e referenciados no código com a anotação [`@FXML`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html).

Não misture swing e JavaFX. Ainda que não haja problemas — *por enquanto* — o recomendável é manter cada coisa no seu quadrado. Todos os componentes presentes no swing, podem ser feitos com JavaFX sem a necessidade de misturá-los. `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` pode ser substituído por um [`TextInputDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputDialog.html) — ainda que seja um pouco mais verboso, vide código de exemplo abaixo.

Pode também utilizar as classes do pacote [`java.nio.file.*`](http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/io/difference-between-standard-io-and-nio/) para manipular arquivos.

```
menuNovo.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {

   // Cria o dialog.
   TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog(null);
   dialog.setTitle("Digite no nome do arquivo");
   dialog.setHeaderText("Digite o nome do arquivo.");;

   // Exibe o dialog e espera pelo valor digitado.
   Optional<String> value = dialog.showAndWait();

   // Se algo for digitado no dialog, cria o arquivo com o nome especificado.
   if (value.isPresent()) {
      try {
         Path file = Paths.get(value.get().concat(".txt"));
         Files.createFile(file);
      } catch (IOException ex) {
         // Tratar exceção no caso de falha na criação do arquivo.
      }
   }
});
```

Se precisar escrever no arquivo, já foi respondido [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217095/4808).